# Is there any way to get a non-iOS tablet's geolocation using FileMaker?

Tags: windows, geolocation, filemaker

FileMaker Go has [`Location`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.32.201.html#1073270) and [`LocationValues`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.32.202.html#1073306) functions available for getting geolocation data. I have a client who is using FileMaker Pro on Microsoft Surface tablets, and would like to find some way to get this same data, basically latitude and longitude, into FileMaker.

I've looked for plugins without success, but perhaps someone else here knows of one that will do the job. Other solutions I've thought of but not yet found specifics for include using Java via the [ScriptMaster](http://www.360works.com/scriptmaster/) plugin or using a website via the [`Insert from URL`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.35.50.html#1144726) script step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 has built in support for geolocation, so you could get this with a web viewer and return the result to FileMaker via an FMP url.

The geolocation function is documented here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp